# huge space between div and iframe

Tags: html, iframe

There is a huge space between div and iframe in below.

I tried to do lots of things but I didn't solve this issue. If I add `margin-left:-350px` that space closes but it is not meaningful to me.

Why is this space formed?

and how can I remove it?

```
<html>
<head>
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
#frame {
    zoom: 0.2;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
<style>
#frame {
    width: 800px;
    height: 520px;
    border: none;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.2);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.2);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="frame" src="http://www.bing.com"></iframe>
<div class="xxx"> Test</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are giving a size and then scaling. Here you have :)

```css
#frame {
display:block;

    width: 800px;
    height: 520px;
    border: none;
   
}
```

```html
<iframe id="frame" src="http://www.bing.com"></iframe>
<div class="xxx"> Test</div>
```

Comment: I want to die :) I think I am so tired, I need to sleep :)

Comment: It is fine. Here is a good place for errors coming from ofuscation. But die is never option ;) Keep calm stay coding